# Floating button was showing under the web page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to show a floating button in my webpage but it was showing like following image.

I want to show that on the page but it was showing under the page. I provided the problem in the image below:

[image: Problem Image]

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the tour first: https://stackoverflow.com/tour and then read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - After you have done that, please edit your question to meet those guielines and add a minimal reproduciable code snippet (**Ctrl + M**).

Comment: Can you expose the relevant code?

Comment: Move the button code to right before closing the body tag. And also set the CSS `z-index` to 9999+ value. If none of these fixes the issue, please share your code or a link to the page where the problem persists.

Comment: Thank you @Ajith Gopi. it was working for me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to display the button on bottom right of the screen (viewport).
So you might do this.

```
.open-button {
    position: fixed;
    top: 90%;
    left: 90%;
}
```

You may change top and left properties' values...